# On click event doesn't find attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z29snL5L/4/)

I have a table populated dynamically with javascript. Under the service column, there is a link (pencil icon) used to display a chat box at the bottom of the screen.  There are tabs used to identify who the person is chatting with.

Problem: One in a while, when I click the chat link, the title of the displayed tab is 'undefined' instead of the persons number.

I'm retrieving the persons number like this:

```
$("tbody").on("click", "a.chat-link",function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Get the link
      var link = $(e.target).parent().closest('a');
      var personCode = link.attr('person-code');

      $(".chat-wrapper").removeClass("closed");
      // hide other tabs
      $("#chat .tabs .list-wrapper .list .scroll-container div").removeClass("current");
      $("#content div.messages-container div.messages").hide();
      $("#content div.messages-container .messages div.message").hide();
      // add new tab and related content
      if ($(".scroll-container div[data-id="+personCode+"]").length === 0) {
        //console.log('new tab');
        $("#chat .tabs .list-wrapper .list .scroll-container").append("<div class='current tab' data-id ='" + personCode + "'><a class='button' title='" + personCode + "' href='#'>" +
                " <span class='name'>" + personCode + "</span><span class='remove'>x</span></a></div>");
        $("#content div.messages-container").append("<div data-id='" + personCode + "_content' class='messages active'></div>");
      }
      // set the newly added tab as current
      $("div[data-id="+personCode+"]").addClass(personCode === 'Admin' ? "current admin" : "current");

      $("div[data-id="+personCode+"_content]").show();
      $("div[data-id="+personCode+"_content]" + " div.message").show();
      $("#content").removeClass("collapse").removeAttr("aria-expanded style");
      //toggle collapse icon
      $('#content-toggle').find('span').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
    });
```

Comment: do you mean that you are not getting :  var personCode = link.attr('person-code');??

Comment: not able to reproduce the issue on that fiddle.

Comment: @DharaParmar yes, what happens is the '007' is displayed as 'undefined'. Somehow, var link = $(e.target).parent().closest('a'); fails so I don't have the link to grab the attribute.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi you have to close the tab and keep retrying.  Eventually it happens.

Comment: Discovered that the area just outside the icon is clickable (link).  Clicking this area is what is causing 'untitled' for the tab.  The solution probably involves changing some css rule so that just the icon is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Edit css file by remove existing padding for `<a>` link, and adding :

```
.status{padding-left: 8px; display: inline-block;}
```

Use the new rule in a separate `<div class='status'>` next to icon.  This eliminates the dead spacing around the icon which caused the 'untitled' tab to appear when clicked.